# Jenkins Tomcat deploymet error

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I have been using Jenkins for quite some time for Continuous integration with my Java projects.

Recently I tried the Jenkins Deploy Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) to deploy my war file on tomcat 7. However, I am unable to do so as I am getting the following error:

```
    Deploying C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MY_PROJS\workspace\target\projs.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
      [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MY_PROJS\workspace\target\projs.war] is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.
      Deploying [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MY_PROJS\workspace\target\projs.war]
    ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
    org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\MY_PROJS\workspace\target\projs.war]
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:187)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:725)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1695)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.pipe(TomcatManager.java:583)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:501)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:547)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:273)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:256)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:240)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:107)
        ... 17 more
    java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.pipe(TomcatManager.java:583)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:501)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:547)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:273)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:256)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:240)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:187)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:64)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:90)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
        at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:47)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:725)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1695)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Still waiting for answer :(

Comment: I have this problem too. Seems to be related to the version being deployed. If the version of the application is the same it works fine but if it's a different version it fails with this error.  I thought changing the display-name in the web.xml would solve it but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, errors like this are simply caused by URL parameter being incorrect.

See similar issue documented/resolved [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15044) where URL parameter was the culprit. Additionally, I highly reccomend thoroughly covering [Apache Manager Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

However, as mentioned in above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004035/jenkins-tomcat-deploymet-error#comment39901362_23004035), this may also be caused by version mismatch between the application itself and what is actually being deployed.